# VBA - Place function in cell. Application-defined object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

Noob VBA user here, please excuse any lapses in correct terminology.

I have a macro that combines a number of spreadsheets, performing a number of calculations etc along the way.

As part of this I wish to place a function in a cell, that would update as data in the spreadsheet changes. (ie, the calculation needs to be performed within the worksheet, rather than in the macro code.)

The function is to check if a particular cell is blank, if so adding it to the sum function, if not it will just add zero to the sum function.

I used this line in the macro to accomplish this:

```
Range("C2:C" & 25).Value = "=SUM(IF(ISBLANK($F$1),E2,"")+(IF(ISBLANK($H$1),G2,"")))"
```

Note.. this works fine when entered directly into a cell as:

```
=SUM(IF(ISBLANK($F$1),E2,"")+(IF(ISBLANK($H$1),G2,"")))
```

However I get a application-defined/object-defined error when trying to run it. Any ideas on how I can make this work? Or is there another route entirely to get a function in a cell using VBA?

Cheers.

Comment: Double the `"` so both the `""` needs to be `""""`

Comment: Thanks so much. I love a simple answer. This works perfectly.